# ошибка в при подключении гема sqlite3 в Rails проект в Ubuntu

Tags: ruby-on-rails, sqlite3

пытаюсь поднять чужой Rails проект и модернизировать его.
логи

```
~/Стільниця/My_RP/Inspinia clean code/Rails_Full_Version$ bundle install
Fetching gem metadata from https://rubygems.org/..........
Fetching version metadata from https://rubygems.org/..
Fetching dependency metadata from https://rubygems.org/.
Using rake 10.4.2
Using i18n 0.7.0
# Using длинный список других гемов
Using sprockets 3.5.2
Gem::Ext::BuildError: ERROR: Failed to build gem native extension.

current directory: /home/leetsworker/Документи/My_RP/Inspinia clean
code/Rails_Full_Version/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.3.0/gems/sqlite3-1.3.11/ext/sqlite3
/usr/bin/ruby2.3 -r ./siteconf20170606-21419-hzoj8s.rb extconf.rb
mkmf.rb can't (еще для корректной подсветки') find header files for ruby at /usr/lib/ruby/include/ruby.h

extconf failed, exit code 1

Gem files will remain installed in /home/leetsworker/Документи/My_RP/Inspinia clean
code/Rails_Full_Version/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.3.0/gems/sqlite3-1.3.11 for inspection.
Results logged to /home/leetsworker/Документи/My_RP/Inspinia clean
code/Rails_Full_Version/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.3.0/extensions/x86-linux/2.3.0/sqlite3-1.3.11/gem_make.out

An error occurred while installing sqlite3 (1.3.11), and Bundler cannot continue.
Make sure that `gem install sqlite3 -v '1.3.11'` succeeds before bundling.
~/Стільниця/My_RP/Inspinia clean code/Rails_Full_Version$ sudo gem install sqlite3 -v '1.3.11'
[sudo] пароль: 
Building native extensions.  This could take a while...
ERROR:  Error installing sqlite3:
    ERROR: Failed to build gem native extension.

    current directory: /var/lib/gems/2.3.0/gems/sqlite3-1.3.11/ext/sqlite3
/usr/bin/ruby2.3 -r ./siteconf20170606-21761-172b5en.rb extconf.rb
mkmf.rb can't (') find header files for ruby at /usr/lib/ruby/include/ruby.h

extconf failed, exit code 1

Gem files will remain installed in /var/lib/gems/2.3.0/gems/sqlite3-1.3.11 for inspection.
Results logged to /var/lib/gems/2.3.0/extensions/x86-linux/2.3.0/sqlite3-1.3.11/gem_make.out
~/Стільниця/My_RP/Inspinia clean code/Rails_Full_Version$
```

Gemfile

```
source 'https://rubygems.org'

# Bundle edge Rails instead: gem 'rails', github: 'rails/rails'
gem 'rails', '4.2.3'
gem 'bootstrap-sass', '~> 3.3.7'
gem 'font-awesome-rails', '4.7.0.1'

# Use sqlite3 as the database for Active Record
gem 'sqlite3'

# Use SCSS for stylesheets
gem 'sass-rails', '~> 5.0.4'

# Use Uglifier as compressor for JavaScript assets
gem 'uglifier', '>= 1.3.0'

# Use CoffeeScript for .js.coffee assets and views
gem 'coffee-rails', '~> 4.0.0'

# See https://github.com/sstephenson/execjs#readme for more supported runtimes
# gem 'therubyracer', platforms: :ruby

# Turbolinks makes following links in your web application faster. Read more: https://github.com/rails/turbolinks
gem 'turbolinks'

# Build JSON APIs with ease. Read more: https://github.com/rails/jbuilder
gem 'jbuilder', '~> 1.2'

group :doc do
  # bundle exec rake doc:rails generates the API under doc/api.
  gem 'sdoc', require: false
end

# Use ActiveModel has_secure_password
# gem 'bcrypt-ruby', '~> 3.1.2'

# Use unicorn as the app server
# gem 'unicorn'

# Use Capistrano for deployment
# gem 'capistrano', group: :development

# Use debugger
# gem 'debugger', group: [:development, :test]
```

как исправить эту ошибку?

Вариант решения, который не помогает:

```
~/Стільниця/My_RP/Inspinia clean 
code/Rails_Full_Version$ sudo apt install sqlite-dev
Зчитування переліків пакунків... Виконано
Побудова дерева залежностей                        
Зчитування інформації про стан... Виконано
E: Не можу знайти пакунок sqlite-dev
~/Стільниця/My_RP/Inspinia clean code/Rails_Full_Version$ sudo gem install sqlite3
Building native extensions.  This could take a while...
ERROR:  Error installing sqlite3:
    ERROR: Failed to build gem native extension.

    current directory: /var/lib/gems/2.3.0/gems/sqlite3-1.3.13/ext/sqlite3
/usr/bin/ruby2.3 -r ./siteconf20170606-22580-tnqs2g.rb extconf.rb
mkmf.rb can't  (') find header files for ruby at /usr/lib/ruby/include/ruby.h

extconf failed, exit code 1

Gem files will remain installed in /var/lib/gems/2.3.0/gems/sqlite3-1.3.13 for inspection.
Results logged to /var/lib/gems/2.3.0/extensions/x86-linux/2.3.0/sqlite3-1.3.13/gem_make.out
```

Comment: Возможно, это дубликат [этого вопроса](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/421225/why-cant-i-install-the-sqlite-gem)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Оказалось, для решения задачи надо было установить пакет разработки руби

```
sudo apt-get install ruby-dev
```

и потом

```
sudo bundle install
```